# What is the difference between using qiskit AerSimulator backends and just calling a simulator backend

Tags: qiskit

So for instance is there any difference between using `backend = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator_statevector')` or `backend = provider.get_backend('simulator_statevector')`
And relatedly are they both ran on IBM's servers and not locally?

Answer (score 3):

In Qiskit, to execute a [`QuantumCircuit`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html) you need a backend which can be an actual quantum computer as well as a simulator. And to get a backend you need a [`Provider`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/providers.html).

Qiskit comes with several providers:

- [Basic Aer Provider](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/providers_basicaer.html): a set of python-based simulators.

```
from qiskit.providers.basicaer import BasicAerProvider
provider = BasicAerProvider()
```

- [Aer Provider](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/aer_provider.html): a variety of high-performance simulator backends for a variety of simulation methods.

```
from qiskit_aer import AerProvider
provider = AerProvider()
```

- [Fake Provider](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/providers_fake_provider.html): a set of backends built to mimic the behaviors of IBM Quantum systems using system snapshots that contain important information about the quantum system such as coupling map, basis gates, qubit properties.

```
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeProvider
provider = FakeProvider()
```

- [IBM Quantum Provider](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/ibmq_provider.html): cloud-based backends hosted on IBM Quantum.

```
from qiskit import IBMQ

# You will need an IBM Quantum Experience account
if IBMQ.active_account() is None:
    IBMQ.load_account()

provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub = 'ibm-q')
```

To get the list of backends provided by any of these providers, call `provider.backends()`. And to get access to one of the backends, call `provider.get_backend(backend_name)`.

---

Now, your question

> is there any difference between using `backend = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator_statevector')` or `backend = provider.get_backend('simulator_statevector')`

`aer_simulator_statevector` is one of the backends of **Aer Provider**. So, it runs on your machine.
`simulator_statevector` is one of the backends of **IBM Quantum Provider**. It runs on the cloud.